# What is the best way to have a program "check in" to a webserver?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a program that will be distributed for free and I am trying to figure out the best way to know how many people are launching my program (not downloading) and from what IP address. This would theoretically give me an approximate number of people launching my program from a company (assuming said company has one external facing IP).

After the program successfully launches it will start this process in a separate thread. I would like it to be simple just checking into a server that will capture the external address. Ideally it would be nice to do from my Linux web host. Should take very little over head.

It would be also nice to expand on. If an error occurred it could quickly send the error to the server as well. Thanks in advanced!

EDIT: Also the ability to send the version would be desirable.

Comment: isn't there a way that you could capture a Count based on the number of people that hit your site..? a HitCount that you can Query.. what do you have so far.. is this something that you have working.. or is this something like a Homework assignment..?

Comment: Why not just have your program make an HttpRequest to your server (just have it load a blank page or something) and check your server logs later?

Comment: Please *tell* your users that the program will try to "phone home", and give them the choice to "opt out" if they don't like this behavior!

Comment: No Homework. I taught my self C#. If a large amount of users use this program then I want to expand it drastically. I really don't have anything yet. I wrote a little script that hits my web server but that does not tell me the version.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Eureka! You gave me an idea, I could have it hit a different page for each version of that app, and even hit a different page on error. Is there any downside to this?

Comment: @paulsm4 I agree, it will be clearly stated and a opt out feature will be included. I personally don't like programs that do this but I understand now why it is necessary.

Comment: just have it hit the same page and put stuff in a query string. `http: //mystuff.com/phonehome/?version=12&ip=12.34.56.78&foo=bar` ... your server should log all of this stuff

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you visit an alternative option I don't see any down fall to that.. many web applications run with these types of metrics without issues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use "ClickOnce" deployment. SEE: [C# Deploying my application - clickonce from web only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408254/c-sharp-deploying-my-application-clickonce-from-web-only)

That way not only will the program "phone home" each time it is launched, it can also check if there are any updates available and offer the user the option of getting the latest version.

All of the information you desire will be in the server's web log. The user wins because he gets updates and you get the added bonus of seeing who chooses to download the updates.

Comment: Unfortunately ClickOnce does not suit my application. Users should not be able to update the application themselves only network administrators. For this the application includes self-updating logic. Thank you for your input though, I did not know you could retrieve launch statistics from ClickOnce.

Comment: Jesse: You state - "Users should not be able to update the application themselves only network administrators. For this the application includes self-updating logic." Are you saying your application updates itself? If so, what is the role of the network administrator?

Comment: To place the latest executable in the repository and authorize the update.

Comment: Jessie: You say the administrator will "place the latest executable in the repository and authorize the update". I believe we are really talking about the same concept. The "repository" is the website, only the admin can put a new copy there. Once there, all users will be notified that a new version is available the next time they run the program. That is what "ClickOnce" is for.

Comment: Maybe I need to do further research into click once.

Comment: Jessie: I work for a firm where many of our people work at home using their own computers. Keeping internal software up to date is a big requirement for us. ClickOnce works perfectly since it is automatic, we don't need to send emails telling of a new version or visit peoples houses to do installs etc. When we get a new employee we simply tell them to go to our company website and click the link to install. Security is easily handled by signing the code with a security certificate, and is optional.

Comment: However the user should have to do nothing. If the admin approves an update the users application should update automatically on next launch. Can ClickOnce accomplish this? Essentially my logic has the program kill itself, delete itself, download the latest executable, and launch the latest executable. The user will never know it was updated since it occurs before the GUI is shown. Whole process takes 4 seconds.

Comment: Jessie: With ClickOnce you have a choice of forcing the user to take the update or allowing him yo choose. The administrator (developer), not the user, makes selects this option.
If you choose the option that the user must accept the update then it will happen automatically before the program is allowed to run. The check is done when the user invokes the program and is done automatically. You do not need to program anything for it to work.