# deploying WPF application to IIS: "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones."

Tags: wpf, deployment, iis-7

I'm attempting to deploy a WPF application to IIS.  After copying the files to the server, when I attempt to download and run the .application file, I get an error:

> Application cannot be started, please contact the vendor.

The detailed log shows the error:

> Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

I noticed someone else [had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227105/clickonce-application-error-deployment-and-application-do-not-have-matching-sec) a while ago.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to me copying the wrong root path up to the web server.  I copied the entire "Release" folder to my target URL, but I needed to copy just the app.publish sub-folder.

I encountered a couple more problems on the way:

1. My deployment included some files in the App_Data folder.  IIS7 was blocking this, and I needed to remove "App_Data" from the "Hidden Segments" of "Request Filtering".
2. I started seeing an error `"my.dll already exists in some-random-temp-folder"`.  I just excluded the DLL from my deployment files.  I think it had already been marked as "prerequisite".

There's an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3408254/1001985) that provides instructions and some context.